# Android Object not locked by thread

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have made a function in my app to delete a record from a database. I am using a seperate activity to do my deleting. When i enter in the row id to be deleted my app tells me that the app has stopped working, but when i click ok it returns me to the main activity screen. I am using a notifyAll() function to update the database and the list view that I have on the main activity, I think this is where its going wrong but I cant figure out why as I am still quite new to android.

this is the activity where i am using the notifyAll()

```
package com.example.rory.dbtest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.pinchtapzoom.R;


public class Delete extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

public EditText edit1;
Button delete;

DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_delete);

    edit1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit1);
    delete = (Button)findViewById(R.id.deleteBtn);

    delete.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);

    }


public void onClick(View v) {

    String userInput = edit1.getText().toString();

    //if the ROW ID its a number (long)
    try{
        long rowID = Long.parseLong(userInput);
        //call the delete method
        db.open();
        db.deleteContact(rowID);
        db.close();
        db.notifyAll();
    }catch(NumberFormatException e){
        Log.e("INPUT ERROR","Input is not a number!",e);
        //notify the user that the input is invalid.
        Toast.makeText(this,"Invalid Value!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.delete, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

This is the logcat error that I am getting

```
object not locked by thread before notifyAll()
```

Comment: why are you doing this in a second activity?? this is not the intention of activitys,... create a thread if you need to a thread can be locked to handle synchron and asynchronus actions

Comment: read the doc for notifyAll

Comment: @Nickolaus I amnt using a thread because i havnt learned about them yet and just stciking with what i know about activities for now. and thanks njzk2 i will read up on them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.notifyAll();
```

the `notifyAll` is a method of `Object`, that is used to wake up all the thread are waiting on this object's monitor. It is not a sqlite-related method, and you don't need to call it (since your db object is not acting as sync-object). You can get rid of that call.

Comment: But what if i am trying to update the listview that i have of the db in my main activity? Do i not need to notify the database that it has been changed after the delete?

Comment: That's another notify and you have to use in the correct way, with loaders and cursor adapter.

Comment: So there is no way of just using a single line to update the list? I have to create a cursor adapter and then use notifyDataSetChanged(); inside of that adapter?

Comment: You could also remove the item you deleted from the db, from the ListView dataset and call notify datasetchanged, but if you go through the CursorAdapter it becomes  automagically

Comment: Im not sure I 100% follow you, would you be able to show me an example?

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```
    synchronized (this){

    }
```

You need lock or sync your method in concurrent requests.